# SSRS column chart with maximum vertical axis

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I have a column chart in which I want the vertical axis to have a maximum value of 50% no matter what the values are.

**Problem**: What ever I do the vertical axis auto shrinks to 20% when values are not greater than say 17%. And as you can see in the screen shot below, the two axis have different scales.

[image]

**Details**: The values have the form of 0.15 and I have set the maximum to 0.5. There are two value fields (two bars side-by-side) and the secondary axis have the same properties as the Primary axis.

[image]

[image]

If I set the maximum value to 1 in both axis it stops auto shrinking and behaves as expected.

[image]

Also, if I change the values from Percent to Number it also behaves strange and auto-shrinks to 0.2.

[image]

Have I found a bug? Is there a workaround?

Comment: In your screenshot, the Maximum property is 0,5 rather than 0.5. I assume you've tried using a decimal point instead of a comma?

Comment: I cant use 0.5 since Im using Swedish locale. I get an error doing that. But thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround!

1. In the Values expression multiply by 100 `=Sum(Fields!ProcFriskaYtor.Value*100)`
2. Right click the axis and change the Maximum to 50 and the Interval to 10
3. In the Axis Properties go to Number and change to Custom number format. Use `0'%';(0'%')` for no decimal points and `0.00'%';(0.00'%')` for two decimal points.

Now the chart has a fixed maximum of 50% and it does not auto-shrink.